# Best way to remote debug a C# mono app running on linux with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono

I am considering developing several console/service type apps for Linux using Mono C#.

My preferred development environment would be Windows with Visual Studio 2013.

Are there any solutions for remote debugging a Mono C# console process running on Linux with Visual Studio 2013?

In an ideal solution a simple F5 would deploy build output to the remote linux host, start the app on the host and then attach a debugger so that I can locally use all the standard debugging capabilities of Visual Studio 2013 (break points, stacktrace, watch window, etc...)

Is this even possible at present?  This add-in here (http://www.giesswein-apps.at/mono) seems like a nice solution but it looks fairly new and I can't tell if it's only for RaspberryPi.

I understand Xamarin provides solutions to cross platform mobile development but do they have any solutions that might make C# Linux development easier?

Comment: I'm also curious if people use VS2013 for Mono/C# development for Linux or is it better to use MonoDevelop?

Comment: I use VS 2013 for Windows and am pretty happy with everything ^^

Comment: @AgentFire is there any tricks to debugging the remote Linux app when developing VS2013?  How is this best accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

The MonoDebugger add-in you linked definitely works on the PC as well, so it's not limited to the RaspberryPi. I have tried it, but as you said it's still fairly new and I found some bugs e.g. while [stepping through a while-loop](https://github.com/giessweinapps/MonoDebugger/issues/1).

Debugging a remote Mono process should also be possible with MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio, but it's apparently not something you can do out of the box: http://tirania.org/blog//archive/2013/Oct.html

Comment: I tried the add-in and had similar crashes to those you reported on GitHub.  In my case I could probably just install MonoDevelop and just debug locally, but I would prefer VS2013.  

Have you specifically tried remote debugging with MonoDevelop?  Any other ideas?

Comment: I didn't try MonoDevelop, sorry.